# Sorting numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort numbers in an array, but I seem to be making my method "runnerTimes" incorrectly.

I want it to be when I call the method "runnerTimes" with any amount of numbers, so it automatically sorts the numbers and prints off the hightest two numbers.

Such that I put in runnerTimes([1,2,3,4,5]) and it comes back with 5 and 4.

Now I could do this by adding (int, int, int ... ) to the method ... but I want it to automatically detect the number of elements in the array and sort based on that.

Suggestions?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class boston_marathon {
// Take a list of times in an array, and show the top 2 times.

public static void runnerTimes(int[] times) {
    Arrays.sort(times);
    System.out.println("The top two times are: " + times[0] + " " + times[1]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    runnerTimes(1, 2, 3);
    runnerTimes(4, 5, 6, 7);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting is overkill for getting the two highest values of an integer array. It can be done in straight `O(n)` time by maintaining two variables corresponding to the two highest values seen so far across a single sweep of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then you could use a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] r = runnerTimes(5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
}

public static int[] runnerTimes(int... times) {
    Arrays.sort(times);
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(times, times.length - 2, times.length);
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
[4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.sort(int[] a)` Sorts the specified array into ascending numerical order. Using this sort method,you must print off the last two elements of sorted array. 
By the way,you want to get the first two elements as highest number, and you can use `sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`(just specify your Comparator). 
Usage:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)